# Python scroller for input

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll, generator

I wanted to start a new project with python, so i saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFFTp.png) so it looked cool so i wanted to give it a try, but i dont know how to make that scroller, all i found online was ways to make it scroll through text and documents, but not to control input, could someone help me make something like this?

and is there a way to make it display the number of characters above the scroller?

this is what i got online, i dont know if its the same thing as what i want

```
scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(master1, bg="green") 
scrollbar1.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Scale widget . Please check this snippet and also please refer https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/scale.html for more details.

```
from tkinter import *   
root = Tk()   
root.geometry("100x100")    
v1 = DoubleVar()        
s1 = Scale( root, variable = v1,from_ = 1, to = 100,orient = HORIZONTAL)      
l3 = Label(root, text = "Horizontal Scaler")      
l1 = Label(root)  
s1.pack(anchor = CENTER)  
l3.pack() 
l1.pack()    
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**

[image: Scale]

If you want the scale value dynamically on moving the pointer of scale and without triggering any button then please check this snippet along with screenshot.

```
from tkinter import *
def get_value(val):
    scale_val = "Scale value= " + str(val)
    label.config(text = scale_val)
root = Tk()   
root.geometry("100x150")    
v1 = DoubleVar()        
s1 = Scale( root, variable = v1,from_ = 1, to = 100,orient = HORIZONTAL, command=get_value)      
l3 = Label(root, text = "Horizontal Scaler")      
l1 = Label(root)  
s1.pack(anchor = CENTER)  
l3.pack() 
l1.pack()
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! I Will check it out tomorrow when I'm on my pc

Comment: there was some stuff i had to change, like i added tk. to the Labels, and put "HORIZONTAL" , in a string, but what i couldnt fix is v1, v1 = DoubleVar() , it says "DoubleVar()" undefined variable

Comment: nevermind, i had to import all in tkinter, but im having another problem , i want the value as a variable so i can later use the number of characters chosen, but variables i type in the function dont seem to work outside it